# tomcat9 not correctly installed on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: tomcat9, ubuntu-20.04

yesterday i installed tomcat9 on my ubuntu 20.04, but when i try to start it from cataline.sh which is on the bin folder under /usr/share/tomcat9 i got the followin error:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat7  
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7  
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat7/temp  
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr   
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
touch: cannot touch `/usr/share/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out': No such file or directory  
./catalina.sh: 389: ./catalina.sh: cannot create /usr/share/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out: Directory nonexistent
```

so i started it normally using the **sudo service tomcat9 start** command and it worked but then for some reason i removed tomcat9 with **sudo apt remove tomcat9** and **sudo apt remove tomcat9-admin** and tried to install it again following the same steps : [tutorial](https://linuxhint.com/install_apache_tomcat_server_ubuntu/)

but since then the service doesn't start and i get this error

:

```
Jun 5, 2013 12:23:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Cannot start server. Server instance is not configured.
```

even in /usr/share/tomcat9 i'm no more able to find the bin folder, any
suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

### Fixing the same issue in Tomcat9 on Ubuntu 20.04

I used apt-get to install and then re-install tomcat9 after doing a complete removal. Similarly, it didn't install the /bin and /lib directories in /usr/share/tomcat9

When I switched to using ***apt*** versus ***apt-get***, it installed the directories.

#### If you originally used *apt-get*

*Include the --reinstall flag if you already have it installed

```
sudo apt install --reinstall tomcat9
```

#### If you originally used *apt*

*Include the --reinstall flag if you already have it installed

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall tomcat9
```

Comment: This approach didn't work for me. I tried both methods, but the bin folder was still not installed.

Comment: What OS and release are you working in? I was in Ubuntu 20.04 at the time.